# Microsoft Graph: as Admin, create events in user calendar

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api

I'm building an application, which will need to send requests to **Microsoft Graph**, and create events in `Office 365` Calendar.

I'm using events endpoint:

```
'users /' + graphdata ['userPrincipalName'] + '/ events'
```

There's no problems when I create events for the account accessing the app.

But I would like to, as ADMIN, grant permission to create these events in the calendar of other users.

I have look in the documentation for some permissions, among the admin permissions, that would allow me to do this, but I did not find anything.

Does anyone know of any way to do this in Microsoft Graph?

I initially believed that the endpoint `users / '+ graphdata [' userPrincipalName '] +' / events` allowed this because one of the parameters is the username of the email account.

The error I get when I try to use this endpoit with another user is: `404: ErrorItemNotFound - The specified object was not found in this store.`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you're authenticated as a user you are using Delegated scopes and you only have access to their mailbox (and any shared with them).

If you want to create events on calendars on *any* account, you need to use the Client Credentials OAuth grant and Application scopes. This process is documented under [Get access without a user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service).